# Ultrasonic sensor is displayed incorrectly in RViz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have an ultrasonic sensor publishing in a topic. I have a distance visualization in RViz. I am getting incorrect display. What could be wrong?

My result:
[image: RViz]

Expected Behavior:
[image: expected]

This is the topic echo:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/$ rostopic echo /ultrasound
---
header: 
  seq: 18316
  stamp: 
    secs: 1651696499
    nsecs: 773573032
  frame_id: "/ultrasound"
radiation_type: 0
field_of_view: 0.5235990285873413
min_range: 0.05000000074505806
max_range: 2.0
range: 0.05999999865889549
---
```

This is the topic info:

```
Type: sensor_msgs/Range

Publishers:
   * /serial_node (http://ubuntu:35161/)

Subscribers:
   * /rviz_1651695997117575758 (http://ubuntu:38335/)
```

Code:

```
#include <NewPing.h>
#include <ros.h>
#include <ros/time.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Range.h>

ros::NodeHandle  nh;

sensor_msgs::Range range_msg;
ros::Publisher pub_range( "ultrasound", &range_msg);

const int adc_pin = 0;

char frameid[] = "/ultrasound";

NewPing u_sonar = NewPing(D6, D7, 200);

void setup() {
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(pub_range);
  
  range_msg.radiation_type = sensor_msgs::Range::ULTRASOUND;
  range_msg.header.frame_id =  frameid;
  range_msg.field_of_view = 0.523599f;
  range_msg.min_range = 0.05;
  range_msg.max_range = 2;
  
}

long range_time;

void loop() {
  if ( millis() >= range_time ) {
    range_msg.range = (float)u_sonar.ping_cm() / 100;
    range_msg.header.stamp = nh.now();
    pub_range.publish(&range_msg);
    range_time =  millis() + 50;
  }
  nh.spinOnce();
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400094/ultrasonic-sensor-is-displayed-incorrectly-in-rviz/) by [ixtora](https://answers.ros.org/users/104000/ixtora/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2022-05-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-05**:
Just for clarity. You said it's being displayed 'incorrectly'. It would make it easier for us if you would also include your 'correct' or more specifically 'desired' outcome.

**Comment by [ixtora](https://answers.ros.org/users/104000/ixtora/) on 2022-05-05**:
@Joe28965, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the soultion, the problem was in this line:

```
range_msg.header.frame_id =  frameid; // "/ultrasound"
```

I changed it to:

```
range_msg.header.frame_id =  "ultrasound";
```

---

Originally posted by [ixtora](https://answers.ros.org/users/104000/ixtora/) with karma: 21 on 2022-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2